# Find nth largest number in array without using sorting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In Javascript, find the nth largest number in an unsorted array without sorting the array.

Comment: need to sort at least a copy of the array, without changing the unsorted array

Comment: You can do that but complexity will be n^2... wouldn't recommend that

Comment: do you need a certain time complexity? becasue you can brute force it for O(n)

Comment: @juvian - That's right, whats the algorothm

Comment: @NickCatib - ohk, how?

Comment: Dillon - No time complexity for the question, anyways O(n) or better would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say array is of size k

maintain its max heap.

then start removing elements of heap while maintaining its max heap property n times.nth element will be the nth largest element.

Comment: No using any sorting techniques sir!

Comment: Now I have changed my answer.